# Compute row-means in a df

Tags: r, dataframe, rows, apply, mean

I'm trying to write compute row-means in my df:

```
mix <- read.table(header=T, text="agrp  1998-1999   2000-2001   tot
1   140903  72208   213111
2   88322   33704   122026
3   18175   3804    21979
4   6125    797 6922")
```

This is the code I've written so far, but I just can't see why it won't work:

```
count <- apply(mix[ ,4], 1, mean)
```

This probably has a very simple and perhaps obvious solution, just can't figure out what the problem is.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please show the expected output for your example. I have no idea what you mean by "count the mean".

Comment: The question is pretty unclear whether you mean "compute the row-means", or "compute the (overall) mean of row-totals". Please edit it to be clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `rowMeans`

```
 transform(mix, Mean=rowMeans(mix[,2:3]), check.names=FALSE)
 #  agrp 1998-1999 2000-2001    tot     Mean
 #1    1    140903     72208 213111 106555.5
 #2    2     88322     33704 122026  61013.0
 #3    3     18175      3804  21979  10989.5
 #4    4      6125       797   6922   3461.0
```

Comment: @Frank49 But, `agrp` I guess is just a unique row.  The mean value will be the same as `tot`.

Comment: That worked brilliantly! I'll obviously need to read more about simple functions in R, trying to migrate from SAS to R. Not as easy as someone might think.

Comment: @Frank49 Which is the one that worked? `data.table`?  I understand that it would be bit hard initially.

Comment: why not simply mix$Mean = rowMeans(mix[,2:3]) and what is the reason for transform?

Comment: @ColonelBeauvel You can use different ways.  It is a choice though.  I used it to show the result in one line..